# Can I implement HttpSessionListener this way?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to tracking valid user Ids in my Java servlet, can I implement HttpSessionListener this way ?

```
public class my_Servlet extends HttpServlet implements HttpSessionListener
{
  String User_Id;
  static Vector<String> Valid_User_Id_Vector=new Vector<String>();
  private static int activeSessions=0;

  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se)
  {
// associate User_Id with session Id;
// add User_Id to Valid_User_Id_Vector
    Out(" sessionCreated : "+se.getSession().getId());
    activeSessions++;
  }

  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se)
  {
    if (activeSessions>0)
    {
// remove User_Id from Valid_User_Id_Vector by identifing it's session Id
      Out(" sessionDestroyed : "+se.getSession().getId());
      activeSessions--;
    }
  }

  public static int getActiveSessions()
  {
    return activeSessions;
  }

  public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
  {
  }

  public void destroy()
  {

  }

  protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    User_Id=request.getParameter("User_Id");
  }

  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    processRequest(request, response);
  }

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    processRequest(request, response);
  }

  public String getServletInfo()
  {
    return "Short description";
  }
}
```

How to get the listener notified when a session ends ? I'm trying to bypass "/WEB-INF.web.xml" all together, is it doable ? Or does it make sense ?

Comment: Since this is related to your original question, as a follow-up, it's probably best to post follow-up questions as a part of your original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't bypass `/WEB-INF/web.xml`. Furthermore, you'll end up with 2 instances of this class, not 1 performing both functions. I suggest you put this Vector in the [`ServletContext`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) and have 2 separate classes.

In the servlet, you get to it via [`getServletContext()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#getServletContext()). In the listener, you'll do something like this:

```
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    Vector ids = (Vector) se.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("currentUserIds");
    //manipulate ids
}
```